# How to add extra columns to an existing migration table without lossing data in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I have one migration table which is responsible for storing details,Inside my database it contains some data ,Now i want to add some two  columns to my existing table without lossing any data in my database (These should be reflected in my database also without effecting any data in my database).i want to add these columns `$table->string('country'); $table->string('station');` in my existing table How to acheive this thing ,please guide me to add columns in my existing table..

`migration table`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateBlogsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('passport_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->integer('rating');
            $table->longText('image');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user_table');
            $table->timestamps();
            //$table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('passport_table');
    }
}
```

Comment: In the docs you can find how to update tables: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#updating-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new migration `php artisan make:migration add_extra_fields_passport_table`, the migration should look like this.

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('passport_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('country')->after('image');
        $table->string('station')->after('country'); 
    });
}

public function down(): void
{
    Schema::table('passport_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('country');
        $table->dropColumn('station');
    });
}
```

You use the migrations, to secure all databases are in sync, local, staging, production etc. If you rewrite migrations, they will not be in sync if some migrations has been executed. I use the `after()` method, to secure a proper placement in the table after the `image` column.

If you are only developing locally alone and nothing has been released you can change the original migration. Then you have to delete the migration row that corresponds to your file in the migrations table and clean up your table structure to avoid errors with rerunning you migration. Alternatively migrations can be rolled back, that is another aproach. Then you can run php artisan migrate and it will rerun the same code again. But it is recommended to just create a new migration, it is way easier.

Comment: Yes, that is what you want? it wont change anything already there, but adding new columns. Similar to ALTER TABLE passport_table ADD country varchar(255);

Comment: yeah that's what i want,Thank you